# How to test drag and drop with vue and jest

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, jestjs, draggable

Is there a good way to test drag and drop with jest and vue and vue.draggable?

I tried to have a look at the test in the [vue.draggable plugin](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable), but I could not find any. Is it really untested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/tree/master/tests/unit

The unit tests are not faking drag and drop in itself, but there are emulating events and DOM manipulation performed by Sortable.js, and test vue.draggable reaction to these inputs

Answer (score 1):

It does not seems to be tested.

This [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-better-tests-for-drag-and-drop-operations-in-the-browser-f9a131f0b281) shows how you could perform drag test with Jest:

```
const getTableCells = () =>
  Array.from(mountNode.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-of-type(1)"));

const createBubbledEvent = (type, props = {}) => {
  const event = new Event(type, { bubbles: true });
  Object.assign(event, props);
  return event;
};

const tableCells = getTableCells();
const startingNode = tableCells[0];
const endingNode = tableCells[2];

startingNode.dispatchEvent(
  createBubbledEvent("dragstart", { clientX: 0, clientY: 0 })
);

endingNode.dispatchEvent(
  createBubbledEvent("drop", { clientX: 0, clientY: 1 })
);

expect(getTableCells().map(cell => cell.textContent)).toEqual([
  "Bob",
  "Clark",
  "Alice",
]);
```

A very well known library for draggable functionaility is from Shopify:

https://github.com/Shopify/draggable

I see they have some test, perhaps you can get some more information by looking at the repository?